# How to set rectangle bounds to the frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Looks like I'm doing everything as in the instructions but the frame doesn't work. Even if I put the usual bounds it stays the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TranslateDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Construct a frame and show it
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(0,0,60,30);
        frame.setBounds(r1);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have the contents define the preferred size that they would like to be and use pack to wrap the frame around it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes to be made:

- That is a very small rectangle (this is important, because most OS's won't allow you to set the bounds of a JFrame to be so small, or else the minimize, exit, etc. buttons will collide.
- I understand that you are using a tutorial or demo of sorts; but, in reality, setting the bounds of a JFrame isn't a really very effective method for accomplishing most anything. Using a layout would be much better in most any situation (but, I could always be wrong :) ).

Please be more specific in what the error is that you are experiencing, if you wish to receive a better answer. I hope this helps you, and best of luck!

Comment: *"I understand that you are using a tutorial or demo of sorts; but, in reality, setting the bounds of a JFrame isn't a really very effective method for accomplishing most anything. Using a layout would be much better in most any situation (but, I could always be wrong :) )."*  You're right this time.  :)  Combine layouts with `pack()` and this becomes a non-question.

Comment: Thank you very much! I haven't even thought that the size matters. I made it bigger and it's working now.

Comment: @Nela no problem at all. Cheers!